# Dataproc: Deployment Manager equivalent of gcloud --optional-components ANACONDA,JUPYTER

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I would like to include `--optional-components ANACONDA,JUPYTER` in my CICD deployment using Deployment Manager

I have tried to place it in python template configuration under metadata secion as well as directly in properties, I checked schemas, existing templates, however I cant find proper spot for it nor anything related in documentation(maybe I missed something, but I only reached gcloud CLI part not DM equvalent)

My expected result would have `--optional-components ANACONDA,JUPYTER` inside :
`

```
resources = []

# cluster X
resources.append({
    'name': 'X',
    'type': 'dataproc.py',
    'subnetwork': 'default',
    'properties': {
        'zone': ZONE,
        'region': REGION,
        'serviceAccountEmail': 'X',
        'softwareConfig': {
            'imageVersion': 'X',
            'properties': {
                'dataproc:dataproc.conscrypt.provider.enable' : 'False'
            }
        },
        'master': {
            'numInstances': 1,
            'machineType': 'n1-standard-1',
            'diskSizeGb': 50,
            'diskType': 'pd-standard',
            'numLocalSsds': 0
        }, 
        'worker': {
            'numInstances': 2,
            'machineType': 'n1-standard-1',
            'diskType': 'pd-standard',
            'diskSizeGb': 50,
            'numLocalSsds': 0
        },
        'initializationActions':[{
            'executableFile': 'X'
        }],
        'metadata': {
            'PIP_PACKAGES':'requests_toolbelt==0.9.1 google-auth==1.6.31'
        },
        'labels': {
            'environment': 'dev',
            'data_type': 'X'
        }
    }
})`
```

Answer (score 0):

Deployment manager only uses the APIs and only [supports certain APIs](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types). For your case to write --optional-components ANACONDA,JUPYTER , please follow [this link](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/ClusterConfig#softwareconfig) as you almost close.To have details about the cloud dataproc components [refer to the dataproc API reference](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/components/overview#available_optional_components).